# Update object using JSP form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

If I pass an object to jsp page, how can I update its fields using setters and send it back?

If for example we have

```
public class Person {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPerson(Model model) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setAge(23);
    person.setName("Jack");
    model.addAttribute("person", person);

    return "updatePerson";
}
```

And a jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form modelAttribute="person">
    <form:input path="age"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

How to make this JSP page send as a result modified person Object, not new with only one field?

Comment: To send A new modified Object you need A new Object handler, preferably configured to accept A form method.

Comment: @nikpon I don't understand, can you give some examples of links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a method in the controller that handles the form submit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String alterPerson(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Note the changes:

- `POST` instead of `GET`: submitting a form by default uses `POST`-Requests.
- `@ModelAttribute` automatically retrieves the submitted data and fills a `Person` object with it

With the form you have the `name` field will always be empty, though. Add another `<form:input path="name"/>` to fix that.

If you don't want to let users change their name, the `Person` object probably shouldn't be in your model at all; it depends on how these objects are persisted, though. You could use a separate object like this:

```
public class PersonChangeRequest {
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And use it as the `@ModelAttribute` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPerson(Model model) {
    PersonChangeRequest person = new PersonChangeRequest();
    person.setAge(23);
    model.addAttribute("person", person);

    return "updatePerson";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String alterPerson(@ModelAttribute PersonChangeRequest personChangeRequest) {
    Person person = findPersonToChange(personChangeRequest);
    person.setAge(personChangeRequest.getAge());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want person to be allowed to change his name. I need only one field to be displayed. Of course I can hide it(using style property display: none), but I don't think it is the best solution.

Comment: Then you need another object, say `PersonChangeRequest` or  `AgeChangeRequest`, that only has an age field, to be in your model; you receive that object, validate it and finally update the underlying `Person` with the new value. The way it's currently set up an attacker could add a name to the POST-Request and the `Person`'s name would be changed. Not having an input field for `name` doesnt prevent that.

Comment: I think this is the only solution. If you post it, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @a76 I've added it to my post.